# CSS grid library that does not conflict with existing code

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, html, css

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551984/wordpress-display-3-columns-each-row-without-using-bootstrap) is the reason I'm asking my question. I wanted to say agnostic library but then you'd be pointing me to http://minicss.org/ which is not really agnostic, at least not in my case.

Suppose you're editing a very old code like the one shown in my SO question. The developer named the div that wraps the html `container` and included everything in it, including the menu.

You cannot use any library like bootsrap because it will see `container` and mess the design.You'd have to waste time trying to fix old code.

I want a library that

- Has special class names so it doesn't conflict with existing code.
- Minimal and responsive, I only want a grid (willing to use a big library in case there's no other option)
- Offered as css, I don't know sass or whatnot
- Available on CDN (optional)
- Gratis and open source of course